# ReSharper 8 Plugin Development Solution Explorer Panel Indicator

Tags: plugins, project, resharper, limit, resharper-8.0

I want to write a ReSharper 8 plugin that will give a visual indication (icon maybe?) to the user in solution explorer panel if the number of projects in a solution exceeds a configurable amount.

Can a ReSharper plugin accomplish this or must I find another way? Must I create a SolutionComponent?

Answer (score 0):

There's actually a set of things that you need to make this happen:

- You need to add a visual element to be placed somewhere. I believe you can define an icon in `Actions.xml`, but as I understand, the solution explorer tool bar contains only buttons, though I could be wrong. An alternative approach would be to actually decorate the solution icon the way that source control plugins do. There are also other approaches, e.g. `StatusBarIndicator`.
- A solution component is essentially some component that exists only while there's a solution loaded. What you need is different - a mechanism of monitoring solution changes and project model changes.